# Degenerations of rationally connected varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective rationally connected variety over $\mathbb{C}((t))$ and $R=
\mathbb{C}[[t]].$

Does there exist a proper regular scheme $\mathcal{X} \to \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ whose special fibre is reduced and whose generic fibre is isomorphic to $X$? I.e. the special fibre is a sum of divisors on $\mathcal{X}$, and I want there to be no multiple components appearing.

Comment: You want the general fibre isomorphic to $X$, I presume.

Comment: Yes, added thanks!

Comment: But still I do not understand the question. There is always the trivial family $\mathcal{X}=X \times \operatorname{Spec}(R)$, right? Maybe you want some additional condition?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi I think $X$ is defined over $\mathbb{C}((t))$, not $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: My intuition is that this is false, but I do not have a counterexample at hand.  The result by Koll’ar in the case of a Fano fibration only gives a “canonical” irreducible component of multiplicity one (and over $\mathbb{C}$ that already follows from the work of Graber, Harris, Mazur and myself).  The work of Hogadi-Xu is similar.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi: The picture to have in mind is a family of varieties over $\mathbb{P}^1$ whose generic fibre is rationally connected, then trying to find a birational modification of the family all of whose singular fibres contain no multiple components.